# range() returns empty list when first argument is larger than the second

Tags: python, range

I have the following lines of code

```
l1 = [1, 3, 1, 2, 10]
l2 = [2, 1, 10, 5, 5]
ranges = [] 
[ranges.append(list(range(x, y, 1))) if x < y else 
ranges.append(list(range(y, x, -1))) for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

I expect this code to print the following

```
[[1], [3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

Instead, I get this

```
[[1], [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4], []]
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Break your code to multiple lines (in other words, **don't abuse list comprehensions for side effects**), run it and debug it and see what values of `x` and `y` cause the output list to be empty.

Comment: Don't switch `x` and `y` in the `else`

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. That was the logical error I made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can dynamically set the stride (3<sup>rd</sup> argument) when calling range, like this:

```
range(x, y, 1 if x < y else -1)
```

---

```
ranges = []     
for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
    ranges.append(list(range(x, y, 1 if x < y else -1)))

ranges
# [[1], [3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

P.S., I prefer using a loop to solve this as I do not recommend using list comprehensions for side effects.